# CMake generate C header via shell script

Tags: c, cmake, build-automation

I have a shell script that takes a JSON file in and outputs a `.h` file which one of my targets depends on. It would appear that CMake's `add_custom_command` is what I need to accomplish this, but I can't get the header file to generate. I have tried just about every combination I could think of using the information from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225005/how-to-generate-a-header-in-source-with-cmake) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827208/run-a-shell-command-ctags-in-cmake-and-make).

Below is the simplest I could create to reproduce the issues I am encountering.

My project structure is as follows:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── main.c
└── res
    ├── generate.sh
    └── input.json
```

#### CMakeLists.txt

---

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(test)

set(TEST_DATA_OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/test_data.h)
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${TEST_DATA_OUTPUT}
    COMMAND res/generate.sh h res/input.json ${TEST_DATA_OUTPUT}
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    COMMENT "Generates the header file containing the JSON data."
)

# add the binary tree to the search path for include files so we
# will fine the generated files
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})

set(SRCS main.c)
add_executable(test ${SRCS})
```

#### main.c

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "test_data.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("%s\n", TEST_DATA);
    return 0;
}
```

#### res/generate.sh

---

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Converts the JSON to a C header file to be used as a resource file.

print_usage()
{
cat << EOF
USAGE:
    $0 h INPUT

DESCRIPTION:
    Outputs JSON data to another format.

EOF
}

to_h()
{
cat << EOF
#ifndef TEST_DATA_H
#define TEST_DATA_H

static const char* TEST_DATA =
"$(cat "$1" | sed 's/"/\\"/g' | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/"\n"/g')";

#endif // TEST_DATA_H
EOF
}

case "$1" in
h)
    if [ $# -eq 3 ] ; then
        to_h "$2" > "$3"
    elif [ $# -eq 2 ] ; then
        to_h "$2"
    else
        echo "no input file specified" 1>&2
    fi
    ;;
*)
    print_usage
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

#### res/input.json

---

```
{
    "1": {
        "attr1": "value1",
        "attr2": "value2"
    },
    "2": {
        "attr1": "value1",
        "attr2": "value2"
    }
}
```

Comment: In out-of-source builds this command will fail and your first link provides a solution. Otherwise read and/or provide the build log to understand what does actually happen when the build process tries to run your custom command.

Comment: What's the target that depends on `generated.h`? Could you please show us your target? `add_custom_command` will only execute if you are trying to build it, or something that depends on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I've gained more experience with CMake, I came back to see if I could get this working. The following shows the 2 lines that needed to be changed.

```
diff --git a/CMakeLists.txt b/CMakeLists.txt
index 6aa2ac6..5d80124 100644
--- a/CMakeLists.txt
+++ b/CMakeLists.txt
@@ -2,8 +2,7 @@ cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
 project(test)

 set(TEST_DATA_OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/test_data.h)
-add_custom_command(
-    OUTPUT ${TEST_DATA_OUTPUT}
+add_custom_target(generate
     COMMAND res/generate.sh h res/input.json ${TEST_DATA_OUTPUT}
     WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
     COMMENT "Generates the header file containing the JSON data."
@@ -15,3 +14,4 @@ include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})

 set(SRCS main.c)
 add_executable(test ${SRCS})
+add_dependencies(test generate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example CMakeLists.txt which uses [Ragel](http://www.complang.org/ragel/) to read an input file (`nstrip.rl`), generate an output file (`nstrip.c`), and compile/link the output file into a binary.

```
set(RAGEL_OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/nstrip.c)

add_executable(
  nstrip
    ${RAGEL_OUTPUT}
  )
set_target_properties(
  nstrip
  PROPERTIES
    COMPILE_FLAGS -std=c99
  )

find_program(RAGEL ragel)
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT             ${RAGEL_OUTPUT}
  COMMAND            ${RAGEL} -G2 -o ${RAGEL_OUTPUT} nstrip.rl
  DEPENDS            nstrip.rl
  WORKING_DIRECTORY  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
  COMMENT            "Ragel: Generating Statemachine"
  VERBATIM
  )
```

Notes:

- with `DEPENDS` the command will only execute when a dependency actually changed.
- This is prepared for out-of-source builds, because it places the generated file in `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR` (ie. the directory in the *build* tree corresponding to the location of the above CMakeLists.txt in the *source* tree), and uses that as input for the executable.
- Likewise, it also executes the command with the `WORKING_DIRECTORY` set to where the above CMakeLists.txt resides, so you can refer to source files (here `nstrip.rl`) with relative paths (you could also do it the other way around).

For your case, you will need to tell CMake where to find the header:

```
# assuming you generate into the build tree
include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}")`
```

Also, if the generating executable is a script which lives in the source tree instead of on the `$PATH`, leave out the `find_program` and just add the script to `DEPENDS`. CMake will then automatically trigger a rebuild of the header whenever you change the inputfile (json) *or* the script itself.